# module(sys) sys is not accessed pylance

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, visual-studio-code, sys

I'm learning python with the book python crash course , i wrote the code for the game alien invasion , but it is not working , when i write "import sys" , the word sys is underscore and the program opens up the screen for like a millisecond and then it closes itself, i look for an answer in this site and YouTube and i haven't been able to find a solution, can anyone help? thanks in advance.

I'm using vs code on Linux mint.

this is what i wrote so far:

```
from settings import Settings

from ship import Ship

import sys

class AlienInvasion:
    """overall class to manage game assets and behavior"""

    def __init__(self):

        """ initialize the game and creates game resources"""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()
    
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)

    
    def run_game(self):
        """start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            #whatch for keyboard and mouse events .
    

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    exit()
            #redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
            self.ship.blitme()

            #make the most recently drawn screen visible.
            pygame.display.flip()
if __name__ == '__main__':

    #make a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```

Comment: Have you tried running it from the command line? When you mouse over the underscored word ("sys") in VS code, what message does it give you?

Comment: hi Sara Messer , this website does not allow me to post pictures , here is the exact words i get when i mouse over : (module (sys) sys is not accessed pylance , quick fix (ctrl+)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there's probably an error being thrown somewhere in your script that is causing the program to stop running, and as such, close the terminal as soon as it is opened. In my experience, this only happens when you execute the script from a file browser UI by double-clicking it.

To fix this, try running the program from somewhere that will stay open, even when the program is terminated, like, for example, the built-in terminal in vscode (you can reveal by going to `view > terminal`). To run the program, then simply run the command:

```
python path/to/my/script.py
```

If it causes an error, you will then be able to see it printed nicely, without the terminal closing.

---

On another note, importing `sys` has nothing to do with this problem. The reason it is highlighted by pylance is that you have imported it, but then you haven't used it anywhere (for example calling a function like `sys.exit()`), so it thinks that the line is unnecessary. It will go away once you use the `sys` module somewhere else in the script.

Comment: hi strike digital , i forgot to change the code to the original form , i try a lot of things before asking in here , the original code reads like this : if event.type == pygame.QUIT:                   sys.exit(). Also i already use the terminal in vscode to try to run the program , i get 3 errors but since the word sys is underscored i assume that is the problem.

Comment: here are the 3 error :  cd /home/fermin/Documents/AlienInvasionGame ; /usr/bin/env /bin/python3 /home/fermin/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.4.1/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/launcher 37321 -- /home/fermin/Documents/AlienInvasionGame/alien_invasion.py 
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.8.10)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fermin/Documents/AlienInvasionGame/alien_invasion.py", line 39, in <module>
    ai = AlienInvasion()

Comment: File "/home/fermin/Documents/AlienInvasionGame/alien_invasion.py", line 17, in __init__
    self.ship = Ship(self)

Comment: File "/home/fermin/Documents/AlienInvasionGame/ship.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
FileNotFoundError: No file 'images/ship.bmp' found in working directory '/home/fermin/Documents/AlienInvasionGame'.

Comment: apologies but this website didn't  let me put them all together.

Comment: Ah, well, that error is saying that pygame cant find the file at the path "images/ship.bmp". Make sure the file definitely exists, and if it doesn, maybe look into using an absolute path (one that starts from a root directory) rather than a relative one.

Comment: hi strike digital , thank you very much for taking the time to answer , isn't the word 'image' a call from the module pygame? and what is an absolute path ? and how do i use that to fix the problem , thanks again for your time.

Comment: "Absolute path" definition and how to find it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/#:~:text=An%20absolute%20path%20is%20defined%20as%20specifying%20the%20location%20of,Relative%20path

Answer (score 0):

According to your error content, I think this is caused by the fact that the file is not found, meanwhile sys is not used in your code.

Here are some reasons caused "FileNotFoundError", you could confirm one by one:

**1. File name and file type**

The wrong file name was inserted into the code. Please carefully check the document name.

**2. Escape of Python string**

In the string of file, the address string information similar to `C:\user\desktop` will be involved, which conflicts with the escape function in Python string, such as `\n` representing line feed. Use `r"C:\User\Desktop"` or `C:\\User\\Desktop` to avoid Python escaping strings.

**3. Relative path problem**

Generally, it is not recommended to use. In the process of Python running, the relative path is the folder that the process points to when running, and the folder is used as the file tree of the root node, that is, if you open the file by using the relative path, you can only access the file under its root node.
You could use the methods `os.path.abspath()` and `os.path.abspath('..')` provided in the OS library to view and change the absolute path where Python runs.

**4. Python runtime location**

If it is such a problem, you can add the following code to the head of the file:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../your/target/path/")
```

Answer (score 0):

try `pip install os-sys` and `pip install syspath`
[enter link description here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/pip+install+sys)